# Scalaz library import technique reasoning

Tags: scala, scalaz

Do any of you know why examples from Scalaz always use this import technique:

```
import scalaz._
import Scalaz._
```

rather than:

```
import scalaz.Scalaz._
```

?  I'm trying to understand what the reasoning behind the preference is.

Thanks!

Answer (score 10, accepted):

I believe it's because `import scalaz._; import Scalaz._` imports all members from the `scalaz` package *and* from the `scalaz.Scalaz` object.

If you will just import `import scalaz.Scalaz._`, then you *only* import members from the `scalaz.Scalaz` object.

Comment: In the first case, also from the `scalaz` package object.

Answer (score 3):

import scalaz._ imports all [type]classes from the core package.

import Scalaz._ imports implicits which make all these classes useful. Like conversions from standard collections to MA and getting Option wrapper and so on.

So you can use one without another.

I believe this is a conscious design decision to allow us survive any kind of implicit-related issues, like [this one](http://groups.google.com/group/scalaz/browse_thread/thread/6ac62baa368c3362/ab6db53e98421080?hl=en&lnk=gst&q=Extermely%20unfortunate%20collision%20between%20scalaz%20and%20Akka%20libraries#ab6db53e98421080).

Comment: Thanks!  This is great additional information to take into consideration.

Comment: Specific elements of a full import can be disabled with the following mechansim: import com.foo.{unwanted => _, _}, and "unwanted" will not be brought in.

Comment: why I really love Scala is because it has tons of great features I needn't learn until the time comes. @pyrony thanks for the tip!